# How to use Compile to optimize the performance of a function calculating the distance between two points?

Tags: performance-tuning, compile

I want to create a function that finds the real space distance between two three-dimensional points. Each point is a list of three real numbers.

I can create functions `dist1`, `dist2`, and `distCompiled1` and test them on example points `myPoint1` and `myPoint2`:

```
dist1[pt1_List, pt2_List] := Sqrt[(pt1[[1]] - pt2[[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - pt2[[2]])^2
   + (pt1[[3]] - pt2[[3]])^2];
dist2[pt1_List, pt2_List] := Sqrt[(pt1 - pt2).(pt1 - pt2)];
distCompiled1 := Compile[{{pt1, _Real, 1}, {pt2, _Real, 1}},
   Sqrt[(pt1 - pt2).(pt1 - pt2)]];

myPoint1 = {1.0, 2.0, 3.0};
myPoint2 = {4.0, 5.0, 6.0};

dist1[myPoint1, myPoint2]
dist2[myPoint1, myPoint2]
distCompiled1[myPoint1, myPoint2]
```

> 5.19615

> 5.19615

> 5.19615

So, `dist1`, `dist2`, and `distCompiled1` all give the same result.

But, I will be computing distances between many millions of points, so **I want to optimize my function for speed.**  If I calculate the distance between 1 million pairs of points, for example, I get the following results:

```
dist1[pt1_List, pt2_List] := Sqrt[(pt1[[1]] - pt2[[1]])^2 + (pt1[[2]] - pt2[[2]])^2
   + (pt1[[3]] - pt2[[3]])^2];
dist2[pt1_List, pt2_List] := Sqrt[(pt1 - pt2).(pt1 - pt2)];
distCompiled1 := Compile[{{pt1, _Real, 1}, {pt2, _Real, 1}},
   Sqrt[(pt1 - pt2).(pt1 - pt2)]];
maxVal = 8.009469032;
numPts = 10^6;
SeedRandom[1234];
coords1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, maxVal}, 3], {numPts}];
SeedRandom[1235];
coords2 = Table[RandomReal[{0, maxVal}, 3], {numPts}];

(* Time the computations, and verify that the functions give the same results. *)
AbsoluteTiming[
dist1Result = Table[dist1[coords1[[i]], coords2[[i]]], {i, 1, numPts}];
]
AbsoluteTiming[
dist2Result = Table[dist2[coords1[[i]], coords2[[i]]], {i, 1, numPts}];
]
AbsoluteTiming[
distCompiled1Result = Table[distCompiled1[coords1[[i]], coords2[[i]]], {i, 1, numPts}];
]
(dist1Result == dist2Result) && (dist2Result == distCompiled1Result)
```

> {6.725385, Null}

> {5.900337, Null}

> {30.191727, Null}

> True

- **Why is `distCompiled1`, the function that uses [`Compile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html), so much slower -- not faster -- than the others that don't use [`Compile`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Compile.html)?**
- **How can I rewrite `distCompiled1` so that it ideally runs faster than `dist1` and `dist2`?**

Comment: Meta question: does you end use actually require computing all point-point-pair distances? Or might you only really require distances between "close" pairs?

Comment: @DanielLichtblau You're right. I only need distances between "close" pairs. But I'm not experienced enough to know the best way to do that; I need to do some research. A simple way might be to divide space into segments, and examine the current and neighboring segments first. Do you have any hints?

Comment: Nearest can deliver all points within a specified radius of a given one. I’ll post an example when I’m back at my desk.

Answer (score 8):

```
distCompiled = 
  Compile[{{pt1, _Real, 1}, {pt2, _Real, 1}}, 
   Sqrt[(pt1[[1]] - pt2[[1]])^2 + 
   (pt1[[2]] - pt2[[2]])^2 + 
   (pt1[[3]] - pt2[[3]])^2],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable}, RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

dist1Result = Sqrt@Total[(coords1 - coords2)^2, {2}]; // AbsoluteTiming
dist2Result = distCompiled[coords1, coords2]; // AbsoluteTiming
dist1Result == dist2Result
```

{0.0334167, Null}

{0.0247759, Null}

True

Comment: Wow, this is an amazing demonstration. It shows the capabilities, in terms of performance, of listability in Mathematica.

Comment: @Karl Did you really use `numPts = 10^6`? Even with the performance improvement with listability, you must have a fast computer.

Answer (score 6):

Karl's answer is perfect as it is. If you know for sure that your input vectors have at least length 3, then it is safe to deactivate the bound checks that *Mathematica* writes into the *C* code. This can be done by the *undocumented* feature `` Compile`GetElement `` insteadl of `Part`. Note that you need `RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"` for this to work correctly.

```
distCompiled2 = Compile[{{pt1, _Real, 1}, {pt2, _Real, 1}},
   Block[{dx, dy, dz},
    dx = Compile`GetElement[pt1, 1] - Compile`GetElement[pt2, 1];
    dy = Compile`GetElement[pt1, 2] - Compile`GetElement[pt2, 2];
    dz = Compile`GetElement[pt1, 3] - Compile`GetElement[pt2, 3];
    Sqrt[dx dx + dy dy + dz dz]
    ],
   CompilationTarget -> "C",
   RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   Parallelization -> True,
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"
   ];
```

On my machine, this makes the function up to 20% faster.

Answer (score 4):

What follows is a more detailed demonstration of [Karl's answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/292240/1185) on this page. This demonstrates the performance improvement (amazing, in my opinion) offered by `Listable` functions in *Mathematica*:

```
(* Initialization *)
maxVal = 8.009469032;
numPts = 10^6;
SeedRandom[1234]; coords1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, maxVal}, 3], {numPts}];
SeedRandom[1235]; coords2 = Table[RandomReal[{0, maxVal}, 3], {numPts}];

(* Functions *)
distAndrew[pt1_List, pt2_List] := Sqrt[(pt1[[1]] - pt2[[1]])^2
    + (pt1[[2]] - pt2[[2]])^2
    + (pt1[[3]] - pt2[[3]])^2];

distKarl[listOfPts1_List, listOfPts2_List] := 
  Sqrt@Total[(listOfPts1 - listOfPts2)^2, {2}];

distKarlCompiled = Compile[{{pt1, _Real, 1}, {pt2, _Real, 1}},
   Sqrt[(pt1[[1]] - pt2[[1]])^2
     + (pt1[[2]] - pt2[[2]])^2
     + (pt1[[3]] - pt2[[3]])^2],
   CompilationTarget -> "C", RuntimeAttributes -> {Listable},
   RuntimeOptions -> "Speed"];

(* Performance testing *)
distAndrewResult = Table[distAndrew[coords1[[i]], coords2[[i]]], {i, 1, 
     numPts}]; // AbsoluteTiming
distAndrewWithMapResult = 
   Map[Apply[distAndrew, #] &, Transpose[{coords1, coords2}]]; // AbsoluteTiming
distKarlResult = distKarl[coords1, coords2]; // AbsoluteTiming
distKarlCompiledResult = distKarlCompiled[coords1, coords2]; // AbsoluteTiming

(distAndrewResult == distAndrewWithMapResult) && 
(distAndrewWithMapResult == distKarlResult) &&
(distKarlResult == distKarlCompiledResult)
```

> {7.979455, Null}

> {8.709511, Null}

> {0.116064, Null}

> {0.062322, Null}

Answer (score 4):

[Answer to a different question...]

The compiled methods are fine if, for each point in one set, you only want to check distances to a small number of points in the other set (the examples have "small" set to 1). If instead you want to know which points in the second are within a specified distance to the first, `Nearest` is the function to use.

```
maxVal = 8.009469032;
numPts = 10^6;
SeedRandom[1234];
coords1 = Table[RandomReal[{0, maxVal}, 3], {numPts}];
SeedRandom[1235];
coords2 = Table[RandomReal[{0, maxVal}, 3], {numPts}];
```

Find all `coords2` neighbors to `coords1` points that are within distance of 0.1.

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 nbrs = Nearest[coords1, coords2, {Infinity, .1}];
 ]

(* Out[81]= {8.00687, Null} *)
```

Check the first few neighbor sets.

```
In[82]:= nbrs[[1 ;; 4]]

(* Out[82]= {{{4.22894, 7.34831, 3.22588}, {4.2806, 7.37094, 
   3.30835}, {4.22592, 7.2422, 3.29461}, {4.25438, 7.32368, 
   3.34095}}, {{0.93075, 5.86791, 4.62192}, {0.877728, 5.88219, 
   4.70008}, {0.928627, 5.96515, 4.66545}, {0.984484, 5.91222, 
   4.69613}, {0.901294, 5.97538, 4.64348}, {0.860855, 5.95889, 
   4.67252}, {0.944867, 5.83116, 4.61225}, {0.924464, 5.80529, 
   4.69967}}, {{4.34926, 3.20961, 5.60807}, {4.36852, 3.25073, 
   5.60718}, {4.34147, 3.28848, 5.63214}, {4.35976, 3.29842, 
   5.56703}, {4.37305, 3.30205, 5.58017}, {4.35996, 3.29815, 
   5.53587}, {4.34908, 3.24295, 5.67379}, {4.30285, 3.31839, 
   5.53733}, {4.30903, 3.25791, 5.49811}, {4.2832, 3.27267, 
   5.66872}, {4.37751, 3.17006, 5.59264}, {4.40635, 3.28206, 
   5.61345}, {4.3599, 3.16009, 5.608}, {4.39588, 3.18371, 
   5.57433}}, {{1.48945, 3.21571, 4.98408}, {1.51413, 3.21257, 
   5.02518}, {1.44867, 3.23852, 5.0191}, {1.50369, 3.21718, 
   5.04696}, {1.47354, 3.15735, 4.98367}, {1.48652, 3.21397, 
   5.06329}, {1.50156, 3.30154, 5.01192}, {1.43768, 3.2166, 
   4.91252}, {1.48613, 3.26883, 4.90126}}} *)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to bother with `Compile`, you could use either of the built-in functions `EuclideanDistance` or `Norm`:

```
AbsoluteTiming[
 edResult = Table[EuclideanDistance[coords1[[i]], coords2[[i]]], {i, 1, numPts}];]
AbsoluteTiming[n2Result = Norm /@ (coords1 - coords2);]
```

Even the second one is slower than `distKarlCompiled` by a factor of 5 though.